# Word Function returning Run Time Error '438 when called in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been creating a macro in excel that will pull information from an excel sheet and insert into a word document.

After much trial and error I have managed to get it to insert all the information I want but I am now stuck on changing the formatting of what is inserted.

After trying a number of different ways to change the formatting inside the macro (none of which worked) I settled on creating a number of functions in word VBA to make the formatting changes I wanted (I.E Change to a style, bold or format to bullet points). These functions work in word with zero problems. But whenever I call them from the excel macro I get a Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method. I double and triple checked I have the word object library ticked, at this stage I'm assuming I'm doing something an excel object doesn't like but for the life of me I can not figure out where the issues is.

Here is a small section of the excel macro, if I run it without calling the word function it works fine. I have tried putting the call inside a with wrdApp with no luck. I also tried pulling it outside of the with wrdDoc but that didn't work either.

```
Sub ExportData()
'
' ExportData Macro
' Export the data from excel into a more usable form in word
'

Dim sheetcounter As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim numbsheets As Integer
Dim numbepisodes As Integer
Dim wrdApp As Object, wrdDoc As Object
Dim episodetitle As String
Dim nextepisodetitle As String
Dim season As Variant
Dim series As String
Dim episodenumber As String
Dim releasedate As Variant
Dim length As String
Dim fndDay As Integer
Dim fndMnth As Integer
Dim hrs As String
Dim mns As String
Dim scs As String
Dim lnglgth As String

Dim sheetname As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lookupRange As Range
Dim datarng As Range
Dim text As Range

Set wrdApp = CreateWord
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
With wrdDoc
numbsheets = Application.Sheets.Count
.Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
.Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

.Content.InsertAfter "Internal Wiki"

Call wrdApp.cntrl("Internal Wiki", "Style", "Title")

.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
```

Here is the cntrl word function

```
Public Function cntrl(txt As String, fnctn As String, optn As String, Optional optnsize As Integer) as Object
'
' A function to control the word functions from excel
'
'
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = fndtxt(txt)

If fnctn = "Style" Then
    Call Style(myRange, optn)
ElseIf fnctn = "List" Then
    Call List(myRange, optn)
ElseIf fnctn = "Format" Then
    If IsMissing(optnsize) Then
    Call format(myRange, optn)
    Else
    Call format(myRange, optn, optnsize)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The fnd txt function

```
Public Function fndtxt(txt As String) As Range
'
' A function to find text and return it as a range. To be used in combination with the formatting funcitons
'
'
Set fndtxt = ActiveDocument.Range
With fndtxt.Find
 .text = txt
 .Forward = True
 .Execute
End With
End Function
```

And the style function.

```
Public Function Style(txt As Range, stylename As String) As Object
'
' A function to apply styles to ranges
'
'
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = txt
myRange.Style = stylename

End Function
```

I split them out into individual functions so I could use them separately if I wanted or together in the control function. I am sure this is not the most efficient way but after working on this for 3 days straight I needed to split things up or I was going to have an aneurism. To be through I tried them as sub's instead of functions and got the same error.

I get the same error for all the formatting functions, I just focused on the style one as this seemed the best way to simplify things and make it easier to explain :). Quite happy to post those as well if required.

Sorry if this has been answered, I had a look through the forums but could not see anything like this.

Would appreciate any and all help this is driving me insane.

**EDIT:**

Thank you very to much to Tim this is now working, here is the changed and working code. I moved the funcs into excel and you can find them below.

Excel Macro

```
Sub ExportData()
'
' ExportData Macro
' Export the data from excel into a more usable form in word
'

Dim sheetcounter As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim numbsheets As Integer
Dim numbepisodes As Integer
Dim wrdApp As Object, wrdDoc As Object
Dim episodetitle As String
Dim nextepisodetitle As String
Dim season As Variant
Dim series As String
Dim episodenumber As String
Dim releasedate As Variant
Dim length As String
Dim fndDay As Integer
Dim fndMnth As Integer
Dim hrs As String
Dim mns As String
Dim scs As String
Dim lnglgth As String

Dim sheetname As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lookupRange As Range
Dim datarng As Range
Dim text As Range

Set wrdApp = Createword
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
With wrdDoc
numbsheets = Application.Sheets.Count
.Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
.Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

.Content.InsertAfter "DnD is for Nerds Wiki"

Call cntrl(wrdDoc, "DnD is for Nerds Wiki", "Style", "Title")

.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
```

The cntrl function

```
Public Function cntrl(doc As Word.Document, txt As String, fnctn As String, optn As String, Optional optnsize As Integer) As Object
'
' A function to control the word funcitons from excel
'
'
Dim myRange As Word.Range

Set myRange = fndtxt(doc, txt)

If fnctn = "Style" Then
    Call Style(myRange, optn)
ElseIf fnctn = "List" Then
    Call List(myRange, optn)
ElseIf fnctn = "Format" Then
    If IsMissing(optnsize) Then
    Call format(myRange, optn)
    Else
    Call format(myRange, optn, optnsize)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The fndtxt function

```
Public Function fndtxt(doc As Word.Document, txt As String) As Word.Range
'
' A function to find text and return it as a range. To be used in combination with the formatting funcitons
'
'

Dim rng As Word.Range
Set rng = doc.Range

With rng.Find
 .text = txt
 .Forward = True
 .Execute
End With
Set fndtxt = rng
End Function
```

The Style function

```
Public Function Style(txt As Word.Range, stylename As String) As Object
'
' A function to apply styles to ranges
'
'
Dim myRange As Word.Range

Set myRange = txt
myRange.Style = stylename

End Function
```

A lot of it came down to adding the word. in front of the ranges.

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.run to run a macro in a word document.  FYI you get the error because the type definition for `Word.Application` is fixed and does not include a method named (eg) `fndtxt`.  You don't mention *where* you put those methods in Word though (in Normal.dotm?) but in any ccase those methods you added belong to a document/template and not to the Application object.

Comment: Hi Tim. The word function is currently in Normal - Modules - Module1 in word. It seems like you nailed the problem on the head. Though even with incorporating your feedback into the code I still get an error, but a different error so that's more progress than I've made all day.

.Content.InsertAfter "Internal Wiki"

Application.Run "Normal.Modules.Module1", "Internal Wiki", "Style", "Title"

Now gives me the error Cannot run the macro "Normal.Modules.Module1". The maco may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. Do I need to move the word functions?

Comment: Unless you need those functions to be in your Word VBA project for other purposes, I'd be inclined to put them in your Excel VBA instead - should work there too.  Have you added the Word object library reference to your Excel VBA project?  You don't show any Excel VBA variable declarations so I can't tell from the posted code.

Comment: I've started to add the marcos into the excel project instead of word. yes I have added the word object library reference. Right now I'm stepping through the macros trying to figure out an argument error I'm getting in the fndtxt function.

ill add the variables to the main post

Do I need to call the word object library reference or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example with all the code on the Excel side:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
    
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'in my testing word is already open
    Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Add()
    
    With doc
        .Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        .Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .Content.InsertAfter "Internal Wiki"
    
        SetTextStyle doc, "Internal Wiki", "Title"
    
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub SetTextStyle(doc As Word.Document, txt As String, theStyle As String)
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = WordTextRange(doc, txt)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.style = theStyle
    Else
        MsgBox "'" & txt & "' was not found", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub


'return a range containing the text `txt` in document `doc`
'  returns Nothing if no match is made
Function WordTextRange(doc As Word.Document, txt As String) As Word.Range
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = doc.Range
    With rng.Find
        .Text = txt
        .Forward = True
        If .Execute() Then 'check that Execute succeeds...
            Set WordTextRange = rng
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Brilliant mate, I could kiss you.

Ill add the changes I made to the code into the main bit. I can not thank you enough

Comment: OK glad that helped - updated to something a little more robust.  Should get you started.

Comment: the problem is the Myrange.Style = styleName.  You can't assign a string to a Style property.

Comment: @Boeryepes - that's not correct. "To set this property, specify **the local name of the style**, an integer, a WdBuiltinStyle constant, or an object that represents the style."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.style

Comment: I know that but it fails unless you set the style. Alas in vb.net interop